# Odd Internet Explorer Rendering Bug (img tag)

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I have a page that has a a call like

```
<%# Databinder.Eval(Me, "Description") %>
```

where the description contains html that gets outputted on my site. It has worked fine for years, but now I am trying to add an img tag in the html, with a width of 740px, which fills the space nicely in lower resolutions.

It works fine in all browsers that I've checked it in (Chrome, FF, Safari) but ie8 adds a bunch of extra white space after the image which causes a horizontal scroll bar.

IE8's developer tool layout tab confirmed that the width of the div containing the img element was something like 1039px, so through inline css I was able to get it to the right size, but all other elements in the description field still have a width of 1039px. When I take the img tag out everything goes back to normal.

I've also made sure to set the img tag to display:block;

edit -- dummy code example:

```
<h1 class="asdf">asdf</h1>
<h2 class="zxcv">zxcv</h2>
<ul>
  <li>zxcv</li>
  <li>adsf</li>
  <li>asdf</li>
</ul> 
<h2 class="qwerty">qwerty</h2>
<p>qwerty</p>
<div style="margin:0; padding:0; width:740px; display:block;"><img style="margin:0; padding:0; width:740px; display:block;" src="images/asdf1.jpg" /></div>
```

So what am I missing?

Comment: I would recommend that you post a snippet of the HTML that can actually reproduce the problem; right now, there is not much information to go on.

Answer (score 1):

In the example code posted the image tag is not closed, I don't know if this is because it is just dummy code or if that could be the issue.  But if the image is just a spacer have you considered using a non breaking space instead?...

`<div style="width:740px;">&nbsp;</div>`

Will cause the space to be taken up by the blocking div element instead of placing an image element inside the div.

Comment: thanks for your input.  I fixed the dummy html.  The image is not intended to be a filler, but is a technical drawing, and I am trying to make it as wide as possible for detail, without needing a horizontal scroll bar.

Comment: Is the image the only element inside of the div?

Comment: yes, so the div would be superfluous I guess, but I thought maybe it would help (like ie was ignoring styling on the img tag).